# set field value if exists using reflactor in java 8

Tags: java

I am set value using refactor in java 8 like this:

```
    public void calculatePump(T entity, Long platformProfit) {
            ReflectorUtil.setFieldValue(entity, "platformProfit",platformProfit );
        }
    }
```

sometimes entity does not contains platformProfit filed, it throw error. Now I am using this to determin field exits:

```
public static boolean doesObjectContainField(Object object, String fieldName) {
        return Arrays.stream(object.getClass().getFields())
                .anyMatch(f -> f.getName().equals(fieldName));
    }
```

but it throw classNotFoundException, how to set field value if exists to improve code's rubust?

Comment: can you please provide the whole code for try.

Comment: The reflection API is slow compared to just using objects normally. Why do you want to use reflection?